# The Metric Extension Lemma of Connes, Gromov and Moscovici

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

This is a question about a proof in the article *Group Cohomology with Lipschitz Control and Higher Signatures* by Connes, Gromov and Moscovici, which may be found [here](http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/5[93].pdf). Namely, their "metric extension lemma" asserts that one can extend a metric from a subspace of a product to the whole space.

The precise statement is as follows and may be found on page 41 of the article:

> Let $Y$ and $P$ be locally compact metrizable spaces, and let $Z\subset Y\times P$ be closed. Let $d$ be a metric on $Z$ such that $d|Y\times p=d_Y$ for all $p\in P$ and a given metric $d_Y$ on $Y=Y\times p$. Then there exists a metric $\bar d$ on $Y\times P$ such that
>     (i) $\bar d|Y\times p=d_Y$ for all $p\in P$ and
>     (ii) $\bar d|Z\geq d$.

I added the condition that $P$ is metrizable and that $Z$ is closed to the statement of the theorem, and both conditions are obviously necessary (Otherwise, one could, for instance, take $Z=(0,1)\subset[0,1]=P$ and $Y=\{*\}$, and the lemma would imply that every metric on $(0,1)$ can be bounded above by a metric on $[0,1]$.)

In the article, the authors first prove the statement in the case that $Y$ and $P$ are compact. This proof seems to be OK to me.

However, when they want to reduce the general case to the compact one, they take a locally finite cover of $Y\times P$ by compact product subsets $Y_i\times P_i$ (as YCor pointed out, every metric space is paracompact.) and equip each of them with a metric as constructed in the compact case. Then they define the final metric as the supremum of the metrics which are bounded above by the constructed metric on every $Y_i\times P_i$, and which equal $d_Y$ on every slice $Y\times p$.

I have three questions regarding this proof:

1. I think one could have arbitrary metrics on $Y_i\times P_i$ if this product is small enough to contain only one point of $Z$. So how can the result have anything to do with $Z$?
2. Can one explicitly describe this "supremum metric"? To be precise, how does one know that the set of metrics with the given properties is non-empty?
3. Can we still prove the lemma in the general case, perhaps adding some condition on $Z$, say, $Z\subset Y\times p$ being coarsely dense for every $p\in P$?

Comment: There are several definitional issues I'd first need to ask. (1) for $X$ a topological space, does "a metric on $X$" precisely mean a continuous function on $X\times X$ satisfying the axioms of a distance? "$d$ a metric on $Z$ such that $d_{Y\times p}=d_Y$ for every $p$": this seems senseless, should it be understood as " $d_{(Y\times p)\cap Z}=d_Y$ for every $p$"?

Comment: Stone: every metrizable space is paracompact.

Comment: "So how can the result have anything to do with $Z$"? I guess this is precisely hidden in this awkward wording "and which equal $d_Y$ on every slice $Y\times p$". It should be "and which equal $d_Y$ on every slice $(Y\times p)\cap Z$".

Comment: "how does one know that the set of metrics with the given properties is non-empty". If Gromov wrote this, it's likely that by metric he does not care with the inconvenient separability axiom. So the non-emptyness is obvious: just consider $\delta((y,p),(y',p'))=d_Y(y,y')$.

Comment: By "a metric of $X$", I suppose they mean a metric which induces the given topology. However, a continuous function satisfying the axioms of a metric (possibly without separability) would be enough for the application in their paper.

Comment: The resulting metric should really equal the given metric on $Y$ on every slice $Y\times p$. This is important because the lemma is used to produce Lipschitz maps all over $Y\times P$ which should then be Lipschitz maps on every slice $Y\times p$ with respect to $d_Y$.

Comment: A metric inducing the topology is usually called "compatible metric". Assuming that they just consider continuous pseudo-metrics seems to minimize the distance to a perfectly rigorous statement and proof...!

Comment: Also my above $\delta$ clearly induces $d_Y$ on every slice $Y\times p$.

Comment: I think the main problem is condition (ii), i.e., the metric should be bounded below by the metric on Z. Perhaps I am missing a point here?

Comment: Of course it's a point, but it does not intervene in the definition of the family of which the authors take the supremum. That this family is non-empty is trivial as I justified. Then it's indeed one issue to show that the resulting supremum is $\ge d$ on $Z\times Z$.

Comment: OK, so I suppose this is an answer to my second question. Thank you very much for that.